# Meta Tags in Website

Tags: html, seo

I have a website, and I need to figure out a few things:

1. Where to put the meta tag?
2. How many meta tags do I need?
3. Can I put all the webpages in 1 meta tag or do I need multiple?

As for my website, there are over 1000 things you can do, so an example would be "John is looking for a poker player." On my website, if you go under board games and click cards, you could add a classify OR if you do a search, you can look for members who play poker/card games. This is one example of thousands of activities.

My question is: do I need to create 1 meta tag for keywords of poker, friend, activity to show up on an SEO, OR can I create 1 meta tag that will hold 1000+ keywords on 1000+ different topics?

My website was created in C#. I'm confused when I google meta tags on youtube and find them written out in notepad as an html.

Comment: if you talk about seo, don't place more than 5-10 keywords per page. if you put 1000 keywords - google or any other search engine will ignore them. beleive it is better even not put any keyword than to put 1000 :-)

Comment: Google pretty much ignores the keywords meta tag. I suggest you google for tutorials using the keywords you have used in your post, for example "meta tag seo tutorial" (and I mean DO A SEARCH ON GOOGLE, not YOUTUBE)

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear !

Comment: rjdown - I have been using google as my bff to locate and understand things. I used a youtube video to watch the "how to's" on meta tags. I understand the programming behind it, so I don't need to youtube it. So you guys are saying, I don't need a meta tag? I apologize, I am so new to this and I may not understand everything unless you talk in plain ol' English :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use Meta tag for keywords !

> The Keywords Meta Tag
>
> A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away, the “keywords” meta tag was
>   a critical element for early search engines. Much like the dinosaurs,
>   this tag is a fossil from ancient search engine times.
>
> The only search engine that looks at the keywords anymore is
>   Microsoft's Bing – and they use it to help detect spam. To avoid
>   hurting your site, your best option is to never add this tag.
>
> Or, if that's too radical for you to stomach, at least make sure you
>   haven't stuffed 300 keywords in the hopes of higher search rankings.
>   It won't work. Sorry.
>
> If you already have keyword meta tags on your website, but they aren't
>   spammy, there's no reason to spend the next week hurriedly taking them
>   out. It's OK to leave them for now – just take them out as you're
>   able, to reduce page weight and load times.

Check this [link](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2067564/how-to-use-html-meta-tags) for crucial parts for your SEO !

This [website](http://seositecheckup.com/) can give you points in which your SEO is not good !

Also it will be good to see how fast your website is responding. You can check this [link](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)

Last 2 links give you detail information how you should fix the problems which you have.

Meta tags should be in `<head>`, css also in `<head>`, javascript if it possible at the end of the `<body>`.

You can check [google web speed test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

**EDIT:**
Here is meta description and title. If your website is written on C# this is probably located in `Site.Master` !

```
<head>
     <title>Not a Meta Tag, but required anyway </title>
     <meta name="description" content="Awesome Description Here">
</head>
```

Comment: If you want your website to be fast in every country, you can check CloudFare and see if this is okay for your website.

Comment: My question to you mybirthname is: I need my website to show up in search engines, like Google, Yahoo, Bing and others. So if you typed in poker activity or poker group or poker friends, then I want my website to show up. The same goes with an activity like movies, football, automobiles, video games, and so forth. I guess what I'm trying to say, how to I make my website show up for any category?

Comment: This will not happen fast, you should have a lot of traffic for something like that. Implement all of the points from the links. It will be really hard to be first when you write poker because they are millions of users which are using already poker websites. Run your website in the links which I gave you(I hope it is already deployed) and check what it is missing. Do you have sitemap, h1 tags, proper meta description, google analysis and so on ...

Comment: I have used Google Webmaster Tools - they state I have missing title tags, I need structured data, I need to improve the data highlighter, I do not have a robot.txt file (robots.txt not found (404)). I paid a programmer to build my site - I have all the code on a remote computer, so finding where everything is located and under what name is challenging. I don't know what sitemap, h1 tags are. I pretty sure I don't have a proper meta description - which is why I'm on here, trying to figure out if I need one and where to place it.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting where to look. To go over this again, I should do 1 meta tag. Can I include more than 20 keywords? Like I said I have 1000+ activities a person can do, so can I include all of those? Should I have a meta tag for home page, about page, and any relevant "main" pages?

Comment: in meta description you should not put keywords, you should describe your page with 155 characters. You can put it for every page, but if you are using master page and you don't have programming experience you will have a problem with that. It will be not easy for you.

Comment: Thanks Mybirthname. I have some research (looking through my code) and seeing what I can do. if I have any more questions, I'll be sure to post them here. Thanks for helping me out. :-)

Comment: @mybirthname the site you linked at says to YES put keywords in meta tags. now what?

Answer (score 0):

1) Meta tags are always in `<head>` element of page.

2) It depends on what metadata you want to add to your page.

3) You will need 1 `<meta>` tag for each meta type. So 1 tag will be enough for your keywords.

You can find more about meta tag on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp).